# Magento 2.2.5 | 'Area Code already set' when using CLI Commands

Tags: command-line-interface, magento2, magento2.2

I installed Magento 2.2.5 (has to be this version) and installed it successfully.

I also used `setup:upgrade` and `setup:di:compile` and other commands.

Whenever I want to use `config:data:import` the CLI reports this error:

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]   Area code is
> already set

I'm using an old dump for now which may cause this error.

Anyone knows how I can fix that? Thank you!

Comment: I encountered this error only on custom code or some 3rd party extension code calling `\Magento\Framework\App\State::setAreaCode()` in the constructor. Any non-core modules active?